# Spotlight for currency conversion

Tags: macos, spotlight, automation

I know that Calculator app has ability to convert currencies but is it possible to get this shortcut in Spotlight like that:

```
currency 100 USD to GBP
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a way, actually. Invoke Spotlight, then type in your text as above. Then use the arrow key to move to near the bottom of the menu, and choose Search Web For... This will do a Google search for your conversion, and you'll get a figure and a graph.

Comment: that is by no means faster or better than the widget.

Comment: @Borderline Your statement is true, but the OP asks for spotlight, not speed. There are legitimate uses to knowing how to use the built in tools without needing to configure widgets or install third party tools. My personal choice to solve this problem is [Launchbar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) and a custom search template for instantaneous search that opens Safari and this URL… http://www.oanda.com/currency/classic-converter?exch=USD&expr=GBP&value=42

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spotlight like this

[image]